# Foreign key add constraint error in laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel

When attempting to run a migration in Laravel, I encountered the following error message:

```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
> (SQL: alter table `campaign_notifications` add constraint `campaign  
>       _notifications_campaign_id_foreign` foreign key (`campaign_id`) references `campaigns` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Below is the migration code I've written:

```
    Schema::create('campaign_notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('campaign_id')->index();
        $table->string('user_uuid')->nullable();
        $table->string('post_id')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('is_opened')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('sent')->default(0);
        $table->string('payload')->nullable();
        $table->string('failed_type')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns')->onDelete('cascade');
 });
```

The error seems to be related to the foreign key constraint on the campaign_id column, which references the id column in the campaigns table with cascading delete behavior. However, I'm unsure why this error is occurring. Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: make sure that `campaign` table is all ready migrated

Comment: Make sure `campaign_notifications.campaign_id` field is of same type as `campaigns.id`. If in `campaigns` table you use `$table->increments('id');` it is `unsignedBigInteger` field type that would need to be added in child table structure.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you already have a `campaign` table in your DB (Take a look in the timestamps of your migrations), so that you can reference the table in your current migration. Basically for this migration to work you need a campaign table in your database, you can't run the `campaign` table migration after this one.

Also, change your `campaign_id` to unsigned integer

`$table->unsignedInteger('campaign_id');
$table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns')->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score 0):

Your migration code will look like :

```
Schema::create('campaign_notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_uuid')->nullable();
        $table->string('post_id')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('is_opened')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('sent')->default(0);
        $table->string('payload')->nullable();
        $table->string('failed_type')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('campaign_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->index('campaign_id');
        $table->timestamps();
 });
```

Comment: Please can you explain your answer.